# Is there any sense using Retrofit with RoboSpice?

Tags: android, rest, networking

I do not understand why should I use RoboSpice with RetroFit, are there any benefits of using it and is it OK to just use standalone RetroFit?

Thanks!

Comment: RetroFit would do the trick itself, why use RoboSpice along with RetroFit anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RoboSpice gives you asynchronous framework that can be used for other things, not just network requests. It notifies your activities (or any other context) of the result of the network request (or any other tast) with respect to their lifecycles.

In other words, it depends on what do you use Retrofit for.